# Add Trino driver to metabase in docker - does not see Trino source in Metabase Web UI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, trino, metabase

I am trying to have Metabase in a Docker container and access Trino through it. So far I have added the trino-jdbc.jar in the plugins folder. But when I access the web ui and I am trying to add a new data source, it only shows the three sample datasources.

This is the part in the docker-compose.yml:

```
metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
    volumes: 
      - ./metabase-data:/plugins
    environment:
      MB_PLUGINS_DIR: /plugins
    depends_on:
      - trino
```

metabase-data is a local folder, in which the jar file is located. If I exec into the metabase container, I can see that the jar file is in the plugins folder.

Has somebody got any idea, why I can not see trino as a source in the web ui?